# xboost dmlc-submit eats command quotes (needed to run python job via scl enable)

Tags: python-2.7, xgboost

I use RedHat 6.8 for my YARN cluster nodes, and it uses Python 2.6.6. In order to get Python 2.7 in RedHat one uses Software Collections. To activate a software collection one must do scl enable. To print Python version for example one does `scl enable python27 'python -V'`

Problem is when I try to submit my Python job to YARN as follows

```
dmlc-submit --cluster=yarn scl enable python27 'python -V'
```

It seems to eat up the quotes and produces this error (instead of the expected Python 2.7.8):

```
Unable to open /etc/scl/prefixes/python!
```

That is the same output one gets when doing following at the bash prompt on any machine

```
scl enable python27 python -V
```

I'm trying to figure out how to fool argparse into letting this through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into argparser (which dmlc-core and xgboost use) source code trying to figure out any possible escaping mechanism. Couldn't find any but did find out dmlc-submit picks up job submission node environment and recreates on each of the execution nodes. Looked at the `scl enable` and `/opt/rh/python27/enable` script and realized LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the important one. PATH is also but for some reason it doesn't carry over so I now specify full path to my SCL provided python27

Following now happily runs on my YARN 2.7.1 cluster

```
cd xgboost
dmlc-core/tracker/dmlc-submit --cluster=yarn --num-workers=9 --worker-cores=4 /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python tests/distributed/test_basic.py
```

Comment: Hi Edi, I met a problem with xgboost. I got "No module named xgboost" when running sample under folder 'xgboost/tests/distributed/runtests.sh'. I would have thought '--files xgboost.egg' should be added as the parameter of 'dmlc-core'. From your running command, I think there is a better way to add xgboost module to node of clusters. Can you tell me how you did it, thank you very much!

Comment: If you download xgboost there's a python-package folder in there - with a README with a bunch of install options, "pip install xgboost" is one, and "python setup.py install" from that folder is another. That's the one I used - on every node of the cluster. Of course you can only do that after you've built and installed the xgboost shared library itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used to think the usage of xgboost with dmlc-core is like pyspark which will copy spark relevant python library to driver on cluster automatically. Now it seems like I have to make the xgboost library manually and submit the executive file with it.